# Finder Connect to Server Opens into VLC

Tags: finder, ftp, vlc

I wanted to connect to an FTP Server using Finder's `Go > Connect to Server` option.
So I try to do so like this:

[image]

But, when I try to do so, it opens in VLC and then VLC crashes.

[image]

Anyone facing a similar problem? What can I do to open it in Finder itself? Do I need to change some defaults? If so, where?

Comment: Nope, not a dupe. I don't want an alternate, I want to fix this.

Comment: I'm sorry, but sftp is definetly **not supported** in the Finder. If you want to use it, you'll definitely need third-party-solutions as described in the linked answer.

Comment: Oh is that so? Let me try ftp-ing then. I'll let you know if that works

Comment: @Asmus yep, you're right. So, third party application it is. :/

Comment: 2018 year - and I've faced this issue. Ridiculous!

Comment: I know this question is old, but for anyone still looking for an answer to _this_ question, simply use `ftps://` instead of `sftp://`.

Comment: ftps:// and sftp:// are usually different protocols, althought often mixed. But yes, both are secure and many providers support both.

Comment: for the future people: there is a correct answer on [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/238048/298203)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the "Connect to Server" menu command in years.  I go into Terminal and type either a command or `open` and a URL that does what I want.  In your case, since `sftp` is a command, try `sftp bang.bong.boom.ac.in`

Comment: This is pretty cool! Doesn't solve the problem, but yes! Terminal based solutions are great. Being a Mac OS newbie, I guess I still have a lot to learn. Either way, there are situations when I'd like to have stuff in Finder. I'll wait for someone to suggest a fix before closing this question :)