# How to set default application for special link types (e.g., ssh://)?

Tags: macos, applications, links

Some applications will signal to the OS that they can open special link type, such as `ssh://` or `github-mac://`.  They get automatically opened for such links by the web browser (or when using `open` in a terminal).  If I have multiple such applications, how can I set which one should be the default?

For example, both GitHub Desktop and SourceTree can handle `github-mac://`. When I installed GitHub Desktop, it became the default handler for these links.  How can I set SourceTree as the default handler without uninstalling GitHub Desktop?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*Update December 2020*
Rubicode (RCDefaultApp) seems to have gone. That leaves [SwiftDefaultApps](https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps) as the new go-to for this task.

*Late Edit July 2019:*
Though RCDefaultApp still works on Mojave, it may not survive Catalina [time will tell]
There is, however, a new kid on the block - [SwiftDefaultApps](https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps), which may become the newer standard. Time will tell (again;)

*Very late edit May 2020.* I have no Mac that can run Catalina, so I'm reliant on others to keep this answer up to date.
From comments, SwiftDefaultApps reported as working in Catalina 10.15.5

---

You can do that with a freeware app called [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/). It's ancient, but still works on El Capitan.
*Update April 2019 - still works on Mojave too.*

You can define the default app for any URL scheme.

I don't have one for github, but this shows how you can set, for example, ftps specifically to any installed app that supports the protocol.

[image]

Comment: it doesn't support extra parameters and adding custom cmd

Comment: Just to report that SwiftDefaultApps works on Mojave quite well!

Comment: Reporting that SwiftDefaultApps 2.0.1 works on Catalina 10.15.5.

Also, you don't need to compile yourself if you don't overlook the Release tab. https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps/releases

Comment: SwiftDefaultApps worked perfectly. Using it on macOS 10.14.6. Link to RCDefaultApp is currently dead.

Comment: @inspirednz - thanks for the heads-up. I've updated the answer to reflect that

Comment: SwiftDefaultApps continues to work as of late 2023, although I'm 'stuck' with macOS Big Sur. There seem to be some minor UI annoyances (e.g., sometimes you cannot click on a radio button, or you _can_ click on it but it doesn't respond, etc.), but the overall functionality remains the same and fully compatible.

Answer (score 4):

You can also try this: https://onflapp.wordpress.com/lincastor/. It allows you to register arbitrary url schemes such as `chrome-devtools://`

Answer (score 2):

Since it hasn't been mentioned yet, there is also a great, modern app called [Choosy](https://www.choosyosx.com) that can be used to change default browser-opening behavior for different links, different times of day, etc.

Comment: It's good to point out that this is a paid app.

Answer (score 1):

And there is [URL Scheme Defaults](https://github.com/relikd/URL-Scheme-Defaults), though not as powerful as SwiftDefaultApps. The app only handles URL schemes and no file extensions, etc.. But it is a standalone app and does not require you to install a pref pane.

[image: URL Scheme Defaults]

Comment: I wish it had an option to disable, not just edit.

Comment: @Nakilon new version published. And if you had reached out via Github, I would have answered earlier ;-) I dont follow this thread actively. ... PS. you cannot simply disable a scheme, but you can provide an application that does not respond to it. e.g., `com.apple.systemuiserver` or `com.apple.dock`

Answer (score 1):

Install duti.  It's the most complete and serious solution to instantly bind UTIs to Appls.  You have it here: [duti on GitHub](https://github.com/moretension/duti)

If you prefer something with Graphic Interface: [SwiftDefaultApps on GitHub](https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps)

Comment: Can't figure out how to use it.