# How to obtain default application associations throughout the system with one tool?

Tags: terminal, finder, mail.app, mojave

I'd like to be able to use the shell (or a GUI would be alright too) to obtain default associations of both filetypes and functions such as Email and the default web browser in one holistic location.

Currently I'm only aware of being able to get the default Mail app definition from Mail.app's preferences, default browser from `System Preferences` -> `General` and then app associations piecemeal by going to files and checking their associations in Finder (Path Finder, or some such tool).  Protocol defaults for `ftp`, `ssh`, etc. would also be nice.

I'm having some odd issues where I would like to obtain all application associations system wide in a single place such as Terminal or a GUI tool.  How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this - so use use RCDefaultApp? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328639/is-there-an-easy-way-to-add-change-modify-or-remove-what-files-or-urls-are-as