# How to open the Apple URL protocol x-man-page:// in iTerm and not Terminal (default)

Tags: terminal, iterm, command-line

Apple has some custom URLs defined and one of them is `x-man-page`.  If you open a particular man page with it, it displays it in a nice yellow window (a provided profile for Terminal) with black text.

```
open x-man-page://man
```

[image]

***Side note:***  You can even put this on a web-page and it will automatically open the man page in the URL.  It was "categorized" as a security issue (Stack Exchange prohibits the URL), but at most it's [a nuisance](https://web.archive.org/web/20180924035936/http://osxbook.com/book/bonus/ancient/urlsecurity/). Same goes for the dictionary app:  `open x-dictionary:apple`, but I digress...

What's nice about it is that it's a separate window and it has it's own predefined profile that can be customized (but I like the default)<sup>*</sup>.  This is the same functionality if you select a command in Terminal with your mouse, right click and select "Open man page".

**I would like to this to work in iTerm2**

Using [RCDefault App](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/328640/119271) I set the application for `x-man-page` and when I issue the command, it does open a new iTerm tab, but it displays nothing.

Does anyone know how to get iTerm2 to respond to this?

---

<sup>*</sup>I liked it so much, I wrote this function in my `.bash_profile` so that if I type `man <command>` it shows up as if I typed `open x-man-page://<command>`

```
function man {
if [ $# -eq 1 ] ; then
  open x-man-page://$1 ;
elif [ $# -eq 2 ] ; then
  open x-man-page://$1/$2 ;
fi
}
```

Comment: An alternative is to use the app ManOpen that shows a man page in a separate nicely formatted window. In macports `port install ManOpen` does this - But seemingly not on Monterey - I have used it for 15+ years. The original site appears to be missing as well but there are forks on GitHub

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem like iTerm actually supports a graphical manpage viewer like Terminal does.

That said, you can force iTerm to open that URL scheme by doing this:

```bash
open -a iTerm x-man-page://ls
```

But when I do that all iTerm does is open a new terminal. It seems like it should at least open up a new terminal with the manpage shown, but it doesn't work for me.  This feature doesn't seem to be mentioned in iTerm's documentation either. It's a mystery why it registers that URL scheme. My guess is that this was an older feature that's no longer supported and it's a bug that it still registers for the `x-man-page` scheme.

Comment: I've filed a bug report here: https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/10911